# Keyboard shortcut to show hover tooltip

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a keyboard shortcut to trigger the information tooltip that is typically shown when hovering over items in VS Code with the mouse?

Example hover tooltip:

[image: Example hover tooltip]

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, that's what you want

Comment: This doesn't work with `vim` mode plugin. The solution is to rebind to another keys like in IntelliJ Idea: `CTRL`+`F1`

Comment: This worked for me on Mac + Vim plugin. The trick is timing. 

Put the cursor over the type, hold CMD/Ctrl + press K. At this point you should see "(CMD K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..." at the bottom bar.

At this point continue holding CMD/Ctrl and press i.

Comment: It's a `Ctrl+K` and then `Ctrl+I`,  **not**  `Ctrl+K+I`. I edited the original answer, I hope the edition will be accepted

Comment: @18augst I'm using the Vim plugin in VSCode and it works. As the previous comment mentions, the correct shortcut is `Ctrl + K` then `Ctrl + I`. Or hold `Ctrl`, then tap `K` and `I` consecutively.

Comment: Would also suggest remapping `extension.vim_ctrl+n` to `<C-j>` and `extension.vim_ctrl+p` to `<C-k>` so you can scroll up and down this popup menu more conveniently than using <C-n>/<C-p> . iirc `<C-j>` already works "out the box" to navigate down this menu but `<C-k` does not

Comment: Works except during debugging mode. It doesn't show up with Cmd+K, Cmd+I on mac. Maybe it is intended?

Comment: why not post name of the command ? i changed the keybind in past but forgot how its called .

Answer (score 95):

If you're using the VSCodeVim plugin, you can use `gh` to show the tooltip.

Answer (score 49):

The corresponding cmd name in VS Keybindings is `editor.action.showHover`. On mac for me the key combo was:

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

You can also access it through your **command palette** by typing `show hover`. It will show you the current keybinding and you can execute it as well.

If you would like [you can remap it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "editor.action.showHover",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

With that, if your cursor is within an error/warning squiggly line, you can hit `ctrl+e` to show what you would normally see with hover.

To make the box disappear, I am having to hit escape. It would be cool if there was a `editor.action.toggleHover` or something like that, but in the meantime this works great!

Comment: When I move mouse out, tooltip is gonna hide :-(
I don't understand how to prevent it

Comment: Any solution in mind to work like as long a key (for example ctrl) is being held it shows, when released disappears? - Like how it does when you actually hover on it with mouse - if you hover on a function, and press ctrl, it shows the definition, if you release ctrl, it disappears. So in my example it would work exactly the same, just instead of mouse hover, it would do it when `editorTextFocus`

Answer (score 7):

2021 Update- As far as I can tell, the new command that we're all looking for here is:

"Show Definition Preview Hover"

The shortcut for that command was unbound. I set it back to ctrl+h, which is what worked for me in the past. Here's more info-

https://newbedev.com/how-to-trigger-documentation-popup-in-vscode

Answer (score 5):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to show all the errors:

[image]

and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to show the list of the Quick Fixes.

Comment: The question was asking for how to show the tooltip, not just how to see all the errors or quick fixes. The tooltip can show other kinds of information, such as variable type, method signature, etc.

Comment: while this isn't an answer to the question this did make it easier for me to use my mouse a little less. Great suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

A simple way, which is also on the [official site of Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf), is the simultaneous use of
**ctr + k + i** are together.

> Just make sure the cursor is on the desired area