# How can I trigger the hover info widget in VS Code using commands or a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

How to trigger a popup with documentation for identifier under the cursor?

Normally it appears when hovering the identifier using the mouse pointer:
[image]

I would like to achieve this effect using a command or *keyboard shortcut*.

The only related commands I found are: `trigger completion` (which doesn't show the function doc) and `trigger parameters hint` (which only works when the cursor is inside function call - parameters list).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut to show hover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279384/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-hover-tooltip)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This is the `editor.action.showHover` command. It is bound to <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> by default.

**Note**: Shortcut works by holding down the <kbd>cmd</kbd> [<kbd>ctrl</kbd> in windows], then while holding press <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>i</kbd>

You can [change the keyboard shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) with a keybinding such as:

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+k ctrl+space",
    "command": "editor.action.showHover",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the equivalent popup to mousing over while holding command ⌘ key?

Comment: for windows use `ctrl` instead of `cmd`

Comment: @skube This is now achievable with `editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover`, which is way more informative than `showHover`

Comment: NOT the @description attribute from jsdoc per the question. It would be extremely useful to see it.

Comment: I just get an 'any' hover. :(

Comment: @MattBierner It just shows function signature and not the docstring. Is there any way to show the docstring?

Comment: @GreenFalcon The contents of the hover is up to the language/extension. File an issue against the extension/language if you want the docstring included in hovers

Comment: You don't need to keep `k` held down, just the modifier key.

Answer (score 72):

The default shortcut for Trigger Parameter Hints is Ctrl+Shift+Space

Comment: This is soooo much easier than ctrl+k ctrl+i

Comment: Even if it was not what Robert asked, this is what I was looking for!
On Mac the command is `⌘ + Shift + Space`

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Space works when the cursor is at the function parameters list.

Comment: [_As a side note_] The same key combination is used _by default_ in **1Password**. So anyone who has 1Password installed should be aware of this moment (both VS Code's and 1Password's shortcuts can be changed if needed of course).

Comment: Maybe this has changed but as of 2024 this key combo does nothing for me and I have no command called "Trigger Parameter Hints".

Answer (score 12):

You also have, with [VSCode 1.40 (Oct. 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_definition-preview-hover-from-the-keyboard):

> ### Definition Preview Hover from the keyboard
>
> There is a new command **`Show Definition Preview Hover`** for better accessibility of the definition preview hover widget, which can be triggered by hovering a symbol with the mouse and pressing a modifier key dependent on the platform and configuration.
>
> Previously, only the command `Show Hover` was provided, which is equivalent to hovering the mouse cursor over a symbol.
> Now, with **`Show Definition Preview Hover`**, the detailed hover information can be shown via the keyboard.

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/definition-preview-hover.gif]

Comment: Note: the theme used in the image is not mentioned in the release note 1.40 page, but it look like https://vscodethemes.com/e/jolaleye.horizon-theme-vscode: https://github.com/jolaleye/horizon-theme-vscode. Slightly more recent version of the same theme: https://github.com/alexandernanberg/horizon-theme-vscode/commits/master

Answer (score 10):

To make this more graphic, check these steps:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Each answer here demonstrates *a different function*. Below is a consolidation of every type of helpful popup, the context in which they come up and all the ways I know to trigger them.

These assume default settings.

## Function: Display documentation

**Shortcut:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

**Scope:** Works over named elements - variable and function names (does nothing over literals).

- Can display function documentation:
  [image: function documentation]
- or variable or even property information:
  [image: variable information]
- *This is the same pop-up you get when you hover over the element briefly.*

---

## Function: Display parameter hints.

**Shortcut:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

**Scope:** Works inside a function call.

[image: parameter hints]

- *The cursor must be inside the parenthesis that contain the passed arguments. Does nothing outside that scope.*
- Can also be triggered by typing a comma, as if passing another argument.
- Up/Down arrows can be used to cycle through overloaded definitions (instead of moving the cursor up and down the document).

---

## Function: Display the code completion menu

**Shortcut:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

**Scope:** Anywhere. Will adapt to the context. In strings will display words only. In code will offer symbol hints - function names, variable names within the current scope, known properties, etc.

[image: code completion menu]

- Is case **in**sensitive.
- Matches all contained characters - they do not have to be consecutive (see image above).
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> accepts the currently selected suggestion.
- Symbol hints can be triggered by just typing letters. Inside strings you must use the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, I couldn't find anything about "hover" in the Key Bindings setting. The relevant command seems to be called "Show quick info" and is bound by default to `Cmd + F1`.

I know this question is about VSCode but I could only find this question when trying to search for an answer. Therefore I would also like to leave the information here in case somebody finds it useful.

Comment: the question is about Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio <year>.

Comment: @MartinRiddar Yeah. I was searching for information for Visual Studio and couldn't find any. Therefore I put the info under this question as well since somebody else might also stumble upon this question as well.

Comment: fair enough, I saw that you updated the answer to include that now :)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to trigger the documentation popup:

**First:** Using shortcut ctrl + space

[image]

**Second:** Using vscode extension:

[image]

Here is the documentation:

[image]

Comment: Very useful extension. Thanks.