# Increase Hint window in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When triggering hints from VSCode, the hint suggestion window is quite small and I can't use the keyboard to scroll it, despite trying a number of combinations. The up and down arrow keys will scroll through the 1/5 hints, but anything else will close the hover preview.

Is there a way to:

1. Expand the vertical height of the hover preview?
2. Use the keyboard to scroll?

[image]

Comment: your second question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57498951/11107541 (the second top search result of googling "`vscode scroll hover`"). I'm not sure. This question is about parameter hints. You can try it.

Comment: related to your first question, but about the width and not the height: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14165, though you can try patching your installation files as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14165#issuecomment-405445745). See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149191 (also about hover widget and not parameter hints)