# How to trigger the REAL documentation pop-up in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

For example, while I am writing code, VS Code shows method descriptions as you see below.

[image]

But how can I see such description for already existing methods? (That is, I want to see the "Forces the control to invalidate ..." message for `Refresh()`). I saw [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455756/how-to-trigger-documentation-popup-in-vscode), but <kbd>ctrl+k</kbd> <kbd>ctrl+i</kbd> was not the thing I was looking for, because it just showed the method signature without the documentation.

[image]

Comment: In VSCode, the hove provider handles that part, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#HoverProvider Therefore, you have to report to OmniSharp guys to see if they can fix that, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues

Comment: So, you mean, currently it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If you put you cursor inside the parenthesis and press "Ctrl + Shift + Space", it might do the trick.