# How to see JS documentation in VS Code rather than 'any'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, documentation, intellisense

How do I configure VS Code to provide JS documentation, for example on the filter method?
Whenever I hover over filter, I get `any` which is highly useless.

[image]

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455756/how-to-trigger-documentation-popup-in-vscode) SO question and was able to get ⌘ + Shift + Space working for triggering parameter hints, but that only works inside parentheses where the parameters go.

(Show definition preview hover doesn't work for me either as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762280/3006011) answer, which makes me sad.)

I've even reinstalled VS Code.

I've tried installing docs view, but that gets `any` too:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're not getting suggestions from JavaScript Array methods because what you're writing is not valid JavaScript. What you've written (`new int[size]`) is like Java / C++ syntax. In JavaScript, you do `new Array(size).fill(0)`. Once you write legitimate JavaScript, you'll get what you want.